# C++ Check String Array for Spaces/Returns

Tags: c++

I would like to make a space/return check for a string array. And a bit more I guess...

The user enters two lines, both being strings. To accommodate for these two lines, rather than making two separate string variables, I made a string array called `string x[2]`. Then the input gets combined into one variable called `string combined` and then outputs everything on one line.

Anyways, I would like the program to allow each line to have multiple strings, i.e. line one is `I like tuna` and line two is `blah blah`. I tried to make this a multidimensional array like `x[2][3]` but then if they enter only one word in a line then this forces them to enter in more lines until the array is completely filled up.

I want the user to enter up to 3 words in each line and a maximum of two lines. So doesn't that mean I have to check for spaces and returns? If so, how?

I don't want to make this post codeless, so for some point of reference, here is my original code which only lets them enter one word per line and two lines:

```
int main()
{
    string x[2], combined;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x[i];
        if (i == 0) combined = x[0];
        else
            combined += " " + x[i];
    }
    cout << combined << endl;
}
/*
```

Program:

```
Hello
World
Hello World
Press any key to continue...
```

I apologize if this post/question is very ambiguous and seems like I haven't put much thought in, but I'm a beginner and haven't been able to figure this one out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Use getline

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    getline(cin, x[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! And how can I make the output identical to the input, with a return in the middle?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) cout << x[i] << "\n";`

Answer (score 2):

Use `getline` to read entire line of input

```
string x[2];
cout<<"input first string"<<endl;
getline(cin, x[0]);
cout<<"input second string"<<endl;
getline(cin, x[1]);

cout<<"Printing first string "<<x[0]<<endl;
cout<<"Printing second string "<<x[1]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is one similar problem in C. there you can't use scanf() if user inputs the string with spaces (cause there will be an error), you have to use gets(), which is unsafe.